# Writing Data to csv file to a single row

Tags: python, csv

I need to write data to a single row and column by where data is coming from the serial port. So I used to read and write row by row.
But the requirement is I need to write data to the next column of a single row In PYTHON.
I need to have filed at the end like this

```
1,2,33,43343,4555,344323
```

In such a way all data is to be in a single row and multiple columns, and not in one column and multiple rows.

So this writes data in one after one row.

```
1

12

2222

3234

1233

131
```

but I want
`1 ,  12 , 2222 , 3234 ,  1233 , 131` 
like every single row and multiple columns.

```
import serial
import time
import csv
ser = serial.Serial('COM29', 57600)

timeout = time.time() + 60/6   # 5 minutes from now

while True:
    test = 0
    if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
        break
    ss=ser.readline()
    print ss
    s=ss.replace("\n","")
    with open('C:\Users\Ivory Power\Desktop\EEG_Data\Othr_eeg\egg31.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        spamwriter.writerow([ s ])
        csvfile.close()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Could you please detail your post with examples and a clearer explanation.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you post the input data that you're working with?

Comment: `ss = ser.readlines()`. Read the whole file in at once and then write it.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r the data in serial port is generated one at a time and written to serial port so it's a loop which read every new data

Comment: Thanks for the code! Indentation in the `while` is not correct. Can you fix that?

Comment: So, you want to write 5 comma-separated integers on a single line... and that's all? Do you run this multiple times to get multiple lines?

Comment: Does this have to happen in real time or is it okay to write the data after all 5 collections are complete?

Comment: @tdelaney  nope . I only read one data at a time and write . So I want to write it to next column(cell) every time and Its happen in realtime

Comment: Could you guess what would be the maximum number of entries you'd be writing this way?

Comment: So all you ever want in this file is a single line with 5 comma-separated values. Do you want that line terminated by a newline character or just the 5 values.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I have around 250 numbers each from 1 to 4 digit

Comment: @tdelaney no all around 250 in single line and 250 column(cell)

Comment: @AzeemAhamed you have 250 numbers but your code only reads 5 numbers and places them in a single row. Its off by a power of 50.

Comment: Wait, you want 250 rows and 250 columns? I'm pestering you a bit because it doesn't sound like you want a csv file at all. csv's express multiple rows of columnar data. I think you just want to collect a bunch of values separated by commas. I'm not sure whether you want any newlines in this thing at all.

Comment: @tdelaney  I need  a csv file exactly and it contain one row and around 250 column. Mean all data in a single row

Comment: @AzeemAhamed - do you need the file updated in real time or is it okay to collect all 250 values and then write it once?

Comment: it okay to collect and write at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv` module writes rows - every time you call `writerow` a newline is written and a new row is started. So, you can't call it multiple times and expect to get columns. You can, however, collect the data into a list and then write that list when you are done. The `csv` module is overkill for this.

```
import serial
import time
import csv
ser = serial.Serial('COM29', 57600)

timeout = time.time() + 60/6   # 5 minutes from now

data = []
for _ in range(5):
    data.append(ser.readline().strip())
    time.sleep(0.02)

with open('C:\Users\Ivory Power\Desktop\EEG_Data\Othr_eeg\egg31.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    spamwriter.writerow(data)

    # csv is overkill here unless the data itself contains commas
    # that need to be escaped. You could do this instead.
    # csvfile.write(','.join(data) + '\n')
```

**UPDATE**

One of the tricks to question writing here to to supply a short, runnable example of the problem. That way, everybody runs the same thing and you can talk about whats wrong in terms of the code and output everyone can play with.

Here is the program updated with mock data. I changed the open to "wb" so that the file is deleted if it already exists when the program runs. Run it and let me know how its results different from what you want.

```
import csv
import time

filename = 'deleteme.csv'

test_row = '1,2,33,43343,4555,344323'
test_data = test_row.split(',')

data = []
for _ in range(6):
    data.append(test_data.pop(0).strip())
    time.sleep(0.02)

with open(filename, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    spamwriter.writerow(data)

print repr(open(filename).read())
assert open(filename).read().strip() == test_row, 'got one row'
```

Comment: This works but this leave the first line . Any possible errors????????????

Comment: @AzeemAhamed - I added a runnable example... try it and let me know what isn't working.

Comment: This one write in the second row and this leave first row blank

Comment: @AzeemAhamed - Embarassingly, I had a bug in the code but it should not have affected the row count. I added a print (its a python 2.x style print - I assume that's what you are using) of the output data. Can you comment back with that exact data so I can see where this blank row is.

Comment: When using 'wb' instead of 'w' then working fine. Thanks a lot bruvvvvvvvv>>>>>>>>>

Comment: Great! In python 2.x, you want `open('test.csv', 'wb')` and in python 3.x, you want `open('test.csv', 'w', newline='')`. That's because the csv writer wants to control the newline sequence completely without the underlying file object also translating `\n` to platform normal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your serial port data wouldn't overrun your main memory heap, the following would be the code that would suit your need.

```
import serial
import time
import csv
ser = serial.Serial('COM29', 57600)

timeout = time.time() + 60/6   # 5 minutes from now

result = []
while True:
    test = 0
    if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
        break
    ss=ser.readline()
    print(ss)
    s=ss.replace("\n","")
    result.append(s)
    time.sleep(0.02)

with open('C:\Users\Ivory Power\Desktop\EEG_Data\Othr_eeg\egg31.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    spamwriter.writerow([result])
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: I got this error 
"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: @AzeemAhamed Did you add the `result = []` before the loop like in the code?